# Sort table by 2 columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

how can I sort my table in SQL by last name then by first name. I have a lot of duplicate last names. My table looks like

```
table(
    last_name varchar(20),
    first_name varchar(20)
)
```

I have written something like this but it does not work properly

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY last_name ORDER BY first_name;
```

The specific sort doesn't matter I can just make it `ASC` or `DESC` depending on what happens.

Comment: ORDER BY last_name , first_name

Comment: Oh man, that was way easier than I thought. I was trying all sorts of `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`. Thanx!

Comment: As a side note,  'SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY last_name' this is incorrect grouping and should not work in postgresql

Answer (score 3):

This is actually quite simple:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY last_name, first_name;
```

Just list multiple order criteria. They are evaluated from left to right. In the above case it will be sorted by `last_name` then `first_name`.

I'm not sure why you wanted to use a `GROUP BY` clause, if you wanted to know how many people share the same *last_name* you can use the `GROUP BY` clause like this :

```
SELECT last_name, COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY last_name ORDER BY last_name;
```

Comment: I think you want to remove the `GROUP BY` in the first query.

Comment: Woops, sorry about that. Copy/paste mistake ^^